# How to encrypt a specific image by its location without opening dialog box?

Tags: c#, winforms, file, encryption

This is the simple program i'm using to encryption and decryption an image. But i don't want to click on button and encrypt or decrypt the specific image. I want to use it in `form_load` and `form_closed`. My image location is `C:\Users\Mateen\Downloads\MyImage.jpg`
. When Form is opened the image should decrypt and show in the picture box and when the form is closed it should get encrypted back.

Any one can help?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
       private void EncryptFile()
        {            
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.Filter = "JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpg|EXE Files (*.exe)|*.exe|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif";
            dialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\Mateen\Downloads\MyImage.jpg";
            dialog.Title = "Please select an image file to encrypt.";
            byte[] ImageBytes;
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ImageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dialog.FileName);

                for (int i = 0; i < ImageBytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    ImageBytes[i] = (byte)(ImageBytes[i] + 5);
                }

                File.WriteAllBytes(dialog.FileName, ImageBytes);
            }            
        }

        private void DecryptFile()
        {
            OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            dialog.Filter = "JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPEG Files (*.jpeg)|*.jpg|EXE Files (*.exe)|*.exe|GIF Files (*.gif)|*.gif";
            dialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\Mateen\Downloads\MyImage.jpg";
            dialog.Title = "Please select an image file to decrypt.";
            byte[] ImageBytes;
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                ImageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(dialog.FileName);

                for (int i = 0; i < ImageBytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    ImageBytes[i] = (byte)(ImageBytes[i] - 5);
                }

                File.WriteAllBytes(dialog.FileName, ImageBytes);
            }            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EncryptFile();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DecryptFile();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you intend to encrypt something decently U should stick with existing encryption techniques. RijndaelManaged for example.

Comment: I don't know that encryption technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems difficult to me. The decrypting part is not hard, but how can you ensure that your program doesn't exit without encrypting? What happens if your program hangs? What if it is killed from TaskManager?

Comment: Then what i'm supposed to do? any suggestions from you please.

Comment: That doesn't matter, the file is already encrypted on the disk. Thus on form_load he only needs to decrypt and hold the object in memory. As soon as the program exits, it doesn't matter how the memory will be released (or at least it should be). And the original file would remain on the disk. But all this is great, if the user doesn't have to do anything (providing a key or whatsoever) then the encryption isn't neccessairy in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

```
var file = new FileInfo("C:\Users\Mateen\Downloads\MyImage.jpg");
byte[] buffer;
using(var stream = file.OpenRead()) {
   buffer =  = new byte[stream.Length];
   stream.Read(buffer,0,(int)stream.Length);
}
```

With the above code your buffer will be the same as ImageBytes that you are having now.

Rijndael encryption Byte[] to Base64

```
    private static string Encrypt(byte[] input, DeriveBytes pwd)
    {
        using (var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            var rgbKey = pwd.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);
            using (var encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, InitVector))
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cryptoStream.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
                        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }
                    var ctb = ms.ToArray();
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(ctb);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static byte[] Decrypt(string input, DeriveBytes pwd)
    {
        var inputBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
        using (var symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            var rgbKey = pwd.GetBytes(KeySize / 8);
            using (var decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(rgbKey, InitVector))
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cryptoStream.Write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
                    }
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

DeriveBytes pwd that's an actual password that can be provided by the user:

```
var derivedPassword = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes("{PasswordHERE}", InitVector);
```

Your code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   private void EncryptFile()
    {            
var file = new FileInfo("C:\Users\Mateen\Downloads\MyImage.jpg");
byte[] ImageBytes;
using(var stream = file.OpenRead()) {
   ImageBytes=  = new byte[stream.Length];
   stream.Read(ImageBytes,0,(int)stream.Length);
}


            for (int i = 0; i < ImageBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                ImageBytes[i] = (byte)(ImageBytes[i] + 5);
            }

            //do something with your encrypted image here.

    }

    private void DecryptFile()
    {
var file = new FileInfo("C:\Users\Mateen\Downloads\MyImage.jpg");
byte[] ImageBytes;
using(var stream = file.OpenRead()) {
   ImageBytes=  = new byte[stream.Length];
   stream.Read(ImageBytes,0,(int)stream.Length);
}

            for (int i = 0; i < ImageBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                ImageBytes[i] = (byte)(ImageBytes[i] - 5);
            }

            //Do something here

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Encrypt()
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
       Decrypt()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't want password encryption, i want to encrypt images

Comment: The second part is a strong encryption for binary data using a password. A password you can set. Take into account not using a password makes your encryption vulnerable since anyone with your program or with program knowledge for that mather can decrypt your files.

Comment: I've added the code in your existing code, the only thing you have to do is use the bytes, either by saving them again or by using them in memory for displaying.

Comment: Are u getting exceptions? Otherwise if you read the comments you would've seen that you needed to complete the methods. You can't expect me to do everything for you...

Comment: No am not getting any exceptions, some errors was there. I've cleared it. but its not getting encrypted or decrypted..

Comment: //do something with your encrypted image here.
Means that you should implement some code to either display or store your image. Next to that your encryption method is very wrong. Adding 5 to every existing byte (byte has a max length of 255) thus when one of your bytes has 251 you will get an overflow.)

Comment: Image img = Image.FromFile("C:\mypath\myimage.png"); 
pictureBox1.Image = img;
i used this after decryption. after encryption it should not be shown.

Comment: So your steps now => Start your program, decrypt your file, (do you save your decrypted file anywhere?), show the file from C:\mypath\myimage.png, close the program encrypt the file, (do you store it?

I would change it to. The program starts, it decrypts the image in memory en shows the image from memory. Also having a button to encrypt your initial image.

Comment: i have stored my images in bin folder, and its not decrypting anyway, and when application starts, the file are modifiable... so i'll try to save it in sql database, about 400 images are there, which are creative. i don't want to loose them.